# How to sort by a fields content?

Tags: 7, database

so I have a content-type called `"Team Member"` and I'd like to sort for the field `"last_name"`.

I currently get all the nodes using:

```
nids = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid', 'field_last_name'))
->condition('type', 'team_member')
->orderBy('n.title','ASC')
->execute()
->fetchCol();
```

So currently, they are sorted using the title. How can I now tell it to sort using `"last_name"` field? I just don't see what exactly db_select needs to know here.

Im on D7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't query the database directly for entity data, there are APIs for that.

In this case you need an [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x):

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'team_member')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_last_name', 'value');

$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot test for now but this could work (considering field_last_name is a textfield) :

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->fields('last_name', array('field_last_name_value'));
        ->join('field_data_field_last_name', 'last_name', 'last_name.entity_id=n.nid');
        ->condition('n.type', 'team_member')
        ->orderBy('last_name.field_last_name_value','ASC')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();
```

Comment: You shouldn't go into the database directly for this, there's an API